# Можно ли стандартными средствами реализовать StackView в iOS ?

Tags: ios7

Можно ли в iOS 7 стандартными средствами из `UITableViewController` переходить в `UIViewController` по клику на ячейку, чтобы при этом родительское `view` не перекрывалось полностью а частично виднелось слева (как `TabBar`, только сбоку) ?  как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите [этот](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) компонент. Там величина перекрытия настраивается кастомно. От полного перекрытия до достаточно сильно выдвинутого вправо по экрану, в примере есть все варианты, пощелкайте по ячейкам таблицы-меню.

Comment: Шикарно, то что нужно, кучу библиотек до этого смотрел, понравилась только эта

Comment: Рад что Вам подошло это решение